LaTeX Workshop: Biber cannot find Thesis.bcf
I'm having some difficulty with Biber and the LaTeX Workshop extension for VS Code. Every time I try to start the build, this error occurs:
INFO - This is Biber 2.20
INFO - Logfile is 'Thesis.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'Thesis.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

The library file is called BachelorThesis.bib and is included in the Config.tex as follows:
\usepackage[
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=ieee,
    giveninits=false,
    natbib=true,
    urldate=long,
    %url=false,
    date=long,                
    dashed=false, 
    maxcitenames=3,
    maxbibnames=99,   
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{library/BachelorThesis}

This is the folder structure:
config
 ┣ Config.acn
 ┣ Config.glo
 ┣ Config.log
 ┣ Config.mtc
 ┣ Config.mtc0
 ┣ Config.tex
 ┗ List_of_abbreviations.tex

library
 ┗ BachelorThesis.bib

Thesis.tex

Strangely enough, the error does not occur when I compile manually via the terminal using:
pdflatex Thesis
biber Thesis
pdflatex Thesis
pdflatex Thesis

I also tried reinstalling the extension but it did not work. The biber PATH is set correctly: /Library/TeX/texbin/biber

Please add a [mre] so we can see if there are any problems in compiling your document

Where is Thesis.blg after the biber call? And where is Thesis.log? (check the dates, to be sure to find the one from the vscode compilation)

Hey, here you go:
[0] Config.pm:308> INFO - This is Biber 2.20
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - Logfile is 'Thesis.blg'
[51] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Thu Jun 27, 2024, 10:34:55
[196] Utils.pm:410> ERROR - Cannot find 'Thesis.bcf'!
[196] Biber.pm:136> INFO - ERRORS: 1


I have faced this issue recently when trying to switch my backend from bibtex to biber.
Other posts suggest to modify VSCode User Settings for Latex Workshop but I kept having the same issue of the .bcf not being found.
The solution that worked for me was to add the --output-directory=%OUTDIR% argument in the biber tool of Latex Workshop. You can do so by opening your User settings (Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)) on VSCode. And then add this argument in the biber tool:
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "args": [
            "--output-directory=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ],
        "command": "biber",
        "name": "biber"
    }
]

Here are the complete list of tools and recipes that I'm using and that might help you:
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk -> bibtex -> latexmk*2",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk",
                "bibtex",
                "latexmk",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk -> biber -> latexmk*2",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk",
                "biber",
                "latexmk",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "bibtex",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "biber",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatex -> bibtex -> xelatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex",
                "bibtex",
                "xelatex",
                "xelatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatex -> biber -> xelatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex",
                "biber",
                "xelatex",
                "xelatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "bibtex",
            "tools": [
                "bibtex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "tools": [
                "biber"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%",
            ],
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "name": "pdflatex"
        },
        {
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "command": "xelatex",
            "name": "xelatex"
        },
        {
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "command": "latexmk",
            "name": "latexmk"
        },
        {
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ],
            "command": "bibtex",
            "name": "bibtex"
        },
        {
            "args": [
                "--output-directory=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ],
            "command": "biber",
            "name": "biber"
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.intellisense.citation.backend": "biblatex",
}

Note that the last line "latex-workshop.intellisense.citation.backend": "biblatex" can also be helpful if you encounter the "No \citation, \bibdata or \bibstyle command" error. It is the VSCode equivalent solution to the one proposed in this post.
It is the case in your code snippet but don't forget to precise the backend when including biblatex by using \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}.
